# How to solve "... memory is not locked" while trying to run Elasticsearch container on Docker Desktop on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, docker, elasticsearch

I am trying to run docker container with Elasticsearch on Windows. The docker-compose.yml file contains following section:

```
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:$ELK_VERSION
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - http.cors.allow-origin=*
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - ./data/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    networks:
      - elk
```

While trying to run the container an error are being logged to the terminal:

ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed

[1]: memory locking requested for elasticsearch process but memory is not locked

How to solve this error? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you might have to configure [VirtualLock](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration-memory.html#bootstrap-memory_lock) in order for `bootstrap.memory_lock=true` to work and bootstrap checks to pass.

Comment: Could you please give me a little more detailed explanation? I don't really understand, thought the mentioned line "bootstrap.memory_lock=true" will solve it. Thanks for the answer